# Generate Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to generate a Crystal Report which is having 2*M columns and N rows. M is determined by user. This 2*M columns will be having values from a single column of sql database. I am firing M SQL queries where every query will fetch 2*N value from a single column.

How can I generate Crystal Report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your report (group by User Id, order by date and time so you will have all I and O for user ordered by time)

**Add two parameters** called StartDate and EndDate

Use `Record - Selection Formula` and then Drag your elements (or type text) so that you'll have:

```
{Comand.Date}>={?StartDate} AND   {Comand.Date}<{?EndDate}
```

Note that date entered by user will be 00.00.00, while date recorded in DB has time. You will have to add 1 day to EndDate to have `<=` instead of `<` .

Comment: thanks greco.. i am developing attendance system from a database. Database has three column userid, datetime and I/O type(0 or 1 value). I/O type determines whether user came in or went out. Now I have to generate crystal report having IN and OUT time for each user from X date to Y date based on user input. For that I am fetching IN and OUT time(based on some conditions) for every user from datetime column using sql query.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the crystal report there is one option for the label report. you can pass the M through the parameter and create the 2*m and N report.